# React - `TypeError: var is undefined` even when var is defined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a React component class. Two of it's method's are:

```
getRandomInt(min, max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);
  };

changeQuote() {
    var randQuoteObj = this.quotes[this.getRandomInt(0, this.quotesNum)];
    this.setState((state) => {
      return {
        randAuthor: randQuoteObj["author"],
        randQuote: randQuoteObj["quote"],
        randColor: this.colors[this.getRandomInt(0, this.colorsNum)]
      };
    });
  };
```

A button has `changeQuote()` as it's `onClick` attribute.

The problem is that sometimes (NOT always, randomly) I get the following error: `TypeError: randQuoteObj is undefined`. If I refresh the page, the page loads properly. The cycle continues.

I've tried making `randQuoteObj` class member, a React `state` property, but nothing has helped. What am I doing wrong? I'm on Fedora and starting the React app using `npm start`.

Solved. Please see comments.

Comment: Can you show us the whole component?

Comment: `getRandomInt` is inclusive (`max` can be hit). You don't show, what `this.quotesNum` is, but i guess it's the array's length, and `this.quotes[this.quotes.length]` would be `undefined`.

Comment: The reason you are having this behavior is that  `this.quotes[this.getRandomInt(0, this.quotesNum)];` relies on the random, that is why it is different from time to time.
It seems like `this.quotes` does not contain the proper value for some of the `this.getRandomInt(0, this.quotesNum)` returned values. Please make sure you have all the values inside `this.quotes`. In case you have more questions please update your question to show  `this.quotesNum` and `this.quotes` values.

Comment: @ASDFGerte That solved it. Thank you.